# Redshift Scheduler unable to create schedule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

My AWS has 2 different Users: `admin`, `s3_readonly`

I am the main admin and have 1 cluster in Redshift(cluster1).
Now I am trying to schedule a query that just calls those procedures every hour `(CALL <procedure_name>)`

For this task, I have followed the official documentation from AWS ([Scheduling a query on the Amazon Redshift console - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/query-editor-schedule-query.html)) and to be exact this document steps ([Scheduling SQL queries on your Amazon Redshift data warehouse | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/scheduling-sql-queries-on-your-amazon-redshift-data-warehouse/)).

So I created new IAM role `RedshiftScheduler`, which has `Redshift Customizable` option and have attached `AmazonRedshiftDataFullAccess` to it. Then I edited the Trust relationship and added:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "redshift.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "S2",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:user/admin"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "S1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

I then went back to my AWS user (admin) and attached a new policy granted with Assume Role permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:role/RedshiftScheduler"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I logged in to the Redshift cluster via AWS service. Used Temporary credentials to connect to `cluster1` and user as `dbuser`. However, when I try to schedule the query it throws an error

> To view the schedule history of this schedule, add sts:AssumeRole for IAM role arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:role/RedshiftScheduler to your IAM role. You also need to add your IAM user ARN to the role’s trust policy.

Comment: Hi @John you can arrive to some solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your IAM user ARN to the role’s trust policy like this

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account #>:user/<admin username"
    },
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    "Condition": {}
}
```

after

```
{
    "Sid": "S1",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
}
```